# Applet throws ClassNotFoundException after signing & updating manifest

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, internet-explorer-11, signed-applet

I have jar file located exactly inside at  /Test2XML/applets/ with name MyIPFetcher.jar. I am trying to make this jar compatible to run on IE8 + IE11 & JRe 1.6 + 1.7.

MyIPFetcher.jar is trying to obtain the IP address of client PC's.

PS: IP address & URL is changed for security reason.

```js
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: https://fakeurl/Test2XML/applets/ 123.23.43.45
Application-Name: IPFetcher Application
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: https://fakeurl/Test2XML/applets/ 123.23.43.45
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: https://fakeurl/Test2XML/applets/ 123.23.43.45
```

```
network: Connecting https://fakeurl/Test2XML/applets/MyIPFetcherApplet/com/IPFetcher/west/logger/ClientLogger.class with cookie "WSIDCookie=AB01; JSESSIONID=0000R29UDciJ8GvaOYcxlkRLka0:16s8ng4ps; BrowserCount=1"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.IPFetcher.west.logger.ClientLogger
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class com.IPFetcher.west.logger.ClientLogger not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.IPFetcher.west.logger.ClientLogger
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.IPFetcher.west.logger.ClientLogger
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

Any suggestion why it is throwing this error ?

Answer (score 0):

JVM is unable to load your ClientLogger class

Check whether your classpath contains that jar and if your classpath doesn't contain the jar then just add that class in your classpath

Comment: How to check it is in classpath or not ? Also any suggestion regarding...i am specifying codebase attribute in java script under applet tag. Do i need to specify in manifest as well ?

Comment: Somehow I added Trusted-Library attribute and this error is gone. Not sure why do I need trusted-library in manifest.